# CSS rule for classes with number greater than

Tags: css, sass, less

My stylesheet looks like this:

```
.thing-1 { background-image: url('top.png'); }
.thing-2 { background-image: url('top.png'); }
.thing-3 { background-image: url('top.png'); }
/* etc... */
```

Followed by this:

```
.thing-20 { background-image: url('bottom.png'); }
.thing-21 { background-image: url('bottom.png'); }
.thing-22 { background-image: url('bottom.png'); }
/* etc... */
```

I am looking for a way to simplify my stylesheet with LESS or something similar. Here's what I'd like to do:

```
.thing-[i < 15] { background-image: url('top.png'); }
.thing-[i >= 15] { background-image: url('bottom.png'); }
```

Is there a way I can do something like this with LESS? If not LESS, maybe SASS?

Comment: JQuery has some pretty good solution attempts for this, have a look at this:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

I think, if you have the option to give your classes more non-generic names, this might be a way:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: While this will make authoring your CSS smaller, it won't actually make your compiled CSS smaller.  Needing to generate class names this way might be a sign of a design flaw.

Comment: I agree with @cimmanon completely ... beneath I try to answer you question directly ... but the best solution would probably be to have only one class selector for each background image and use that in the respective place in the markup.

Comment: @everyone sorry it took me so long to get back around to this. This might seem like a design flaw but it should become a little clearer why I have all these classes if you imagine musical notes on a stave (e.g. .note-1, .note-2, .note-3). Each one has its own vertical (and sometimes horizontal) position along with other styles, so I was hoping for a way to grab all the (for instance) top notes at once and invert them so the stems are facing downwards. Thanks for the great ideas!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you are asking for LESS and Sass, here are some solutions. You can achieve it in both with looping through values - but Sass is a bit stronger in this field as it has built-in control directives like `@for`, `@if`, `@while` and `@each`. There are of course multiple ways of implementing this but this were the first that came to mind:

**LESS:**

```
.bg (@i) when (@i < 15) { background-image: url('top.png'); }
.bg (@i) when (@i >= 15) { background-image: url('bottom.png'); }

.things (@max, @i: 1) when (@i < @max) {
  .thing-@{i} { .bg (@i); }
  .things (@max, (@i + 1));
}

.things(50);
```

and **SCSS:**

```
@function bg($i) {
  @if $i < 15 { @return 'top.png' }
  @else { @return 'bottom.png' }
}

@for $i from 1 through 50 {
  .thing-#{$i} { background-image: url(bg($i)); }
}
```

where you achieve your exact output.

But a more **dry** output would be achieved with:

**LESS:** see [@seven-phases-max's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736971/css-rule-for-classes-with-number-greater-than/19737428#19737428). However, there is the problem of always having to print out `.thing-15` also if you only have less than 15 items. Unless you add another guard that adds `.thing-15` only when needed like so:

```
.thing(@i) when (@i = 15) {
    .thing-15 {background-image: url('bottom.png')}
}
```

you can try out the Less solutions at [less2css.org](http://less2css.org/)

or **SCSS:**

```
%bg-top { background-image: url('top.png'); }
%bg-bottom { background-image: url('bottom.png'); }

@for $i from 1 through 50 {
  .thing-#{$i} {
    @if $i < 15 { @extend %bg-top; }
    @else { @extend %bg-bottom; }
  }
}
```

The last one in my opinion is the most elegant solution.

## [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7273861)

Comment: is there a way we can detect if an attribute is less than a value? ie img[width<"500"] ?

Answer (score 5):

### Preprocessor Not Particularly Needed Under Some Conditions

**Update**: Made the solution fully general to allow for extra classes on either side of `thing-#` class.

This is fairly practical with the numbers you are dealing with. Basically the technique is similar to [what I answered for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504543/assign-css-attributes-according-to-class-range/13532326#13532326), but in your case the code is as follows ([here is a tweaked example just using background color](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTkuN/7/)):

```
[class*="thing-"] {
    background-image: url('top.png');
}

[class*="thing-1"]:not(.thing-1):not(.thing-10):not(.thing-11):not(.thing-12):not(.thing-13):not(.thing-14),
[class*="thing-2"]:not(.thing-2),
[class*="thing-3"]:not(.thing-3),
[class*="thing-4"]:not(.thing-4),
[class*="thing-5"]:not(.thing-5),
[class*="thing-6"]:not(.thing-6),
[class*="thing-7"]:not(.thing-7),
[class*="thing-8"]:not(.thing-8),
[class*="thing-9"]:not(.thing-9) {
    background-image: url('bottom.png');
}
```

It uses the attribute selector when it is doing a "general" selection across multiple numbers, and then filters out for specific classes that the general should not apply to.

### You Can Reduce the CSS Further

If you change your `1-9` classes to have preceeding zeros (`thing-01`, `thing-02` etc.), then the general css [can be reduced further to this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTkuN/6/):

```
[class*="thing-"] {
    background-image: url('top.png');
}

[class*="thing-"]:not([class*="thing-0"]):not(.thing-10):not(.thing-11):not(.thing-12):not(.thing-13):not(.thing-14) {
    background-image: url('bottom.png');
}
```

### Practical Limits

This would all get very cumbersome if a break point at a very large number was needed, as more filtering would need to occur. But still [some larger levels can be achieved for breaking as my original answer for the other question demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504543/assign-css-attributes-according-to-class-range/13532326#13532326), and at that point, perhaps using LESS or SCSS to somehow do the break pointing might be possible, while still keeping output CSS low.

Comment: +1 for the  nice idea. I still think this looks a bi messier than a preprocessed output, but also I would just use two class selectors and not have to have so many classes with the same properties. Anyways, @ScottS congrats on your LESS silver badge ;-)

Comment: @MartinTurjak: Thanks for the congrats (you knew before me!), and the vote to push me over. Yes, my solution is "messier" in its look, but it is less (that's "pun"-ny) lines of actually css code, and mine accommodates ALL values higher than 15, whereas your example (for instance) accommodates only up to `thing-49`, and if one needed to accommodate `thing-100` you would need to add another 51 lines of css output, or `thing-10000` ... whereas mine stays the same no matter the value above 15.

Comment: I totally agree with you (no need to convince me any further =) - what I meant was that I wouldn't even go the path the OP took and keep it just to `.bg-top { background-image: url('top.png'); }` and `.bg-bottom { background-image: url('bottom.png'); }` or so - then you would always just have 2 lines of CSS =)

Comment: @MartinTurjak: Ah yes, I see what you were saying. Yeah, I'm not sure why that is not an option for the OP. Take a look, however, at my reduced code version with a tweak of the class structure. Also, I made the base answer fully general to allow classes on either side of the `thing-#` class possible.

Comment: that looks much tidier now ;-) but I already gave you my +1 heh ... ah and you got your silver badge so you can't complain =P

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this in LESS. However the code is a bit scary (basically it will require you to learn some advanced LESS concepts) so if your use-case is that simple I guess you'd prefer to just write these things manually (as suggested by @Ashkan).

---

LESS code:

```
.thing-1  {background-image: url('top.png')}
.thing-15 {background-image: url('bottom.png')}

.thing(@i) when (@i < 15) {
    .thing-@{i} {&:extend(.thing-1);}
}
.thing(@i) when (@i > 15) {
    .thing-@{i} {&:extend(.thing-15);}
}

.generate-things(@i) when (@i > 1) {
    .generate-things((@i - 1));
    .thing(@i);
}

.generate-things(30);
```

Comment: +1 for the solution. Last night I just referred to your answer as we were answering kinda at the same time and forgot to upvote it =) And as I already stated in my answer .. your solution would be a bit more general if you would add an extra guard that adds `.thing-15` only when `@i = 15`.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Yes, it could be a bit smarter but I did not want it to become even more scary. It's OK I guess, assuming it's only an example and you still have to edit too many things manually (like changing all those `15`, `30` if you need other numbers)...

Answer (score 2):

you can do either

```
.thing-1,.thing-2,.thing-3,... { background-image: url('top.png'); }
.thing-20,.thing-21,.thing-22,... { background-image: url('bottom.png'); }
```

of you can use more than one class for your elements:

```
.top { background-image: url('top.png'); }
.bottom { background-image: url('bottom.png'); }
.thing-1 { /*only thing-1 related css code*/}
.thing-2 { /*only thing-2 related css code*/}
```

and use it like:

```
<div class="top thing-1"></div>
<div class="bottom thing-1"></div>
```