# CSS selector to match class with number greater than

Tags: css, sass

I have a mobile hybrid application developed with Sencha Touch 2 which needs some customization based on the iOS version it is running on.

I used to have the following selector in my Sass stylesheet:

```
.x-ios-7 {
/* put here iOS7 customizations */

}
```

Now with iOS8 the framework adds a `x-ios-8` class instead of `x-ios-7` and the customizations are obviously broken.

Is there a way to select all classes with `x-ios-{i}` where `{i}` >= 7?

[EDIT]

Sass usage is allowed.
I don't want to hardcode known cases.

Comment: Not possible with CSS. JS/JQ is the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS rule for classes with number greater than](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736971/css-rule-for-classes-with-number-greater-than)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### SASS

```
@for $i from 3 through 6 {
    .x-ios-#{$i} { background:blue; }
}
```

generates

```
.x-ios-3 { background:blue; }
.x-ios-4 { background:blue; }
.x-ios-5 { background:blue; }
.x-ios-6 { background:blue; }
```

### Regular CSS

```
div { width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black;float:left; }
[class^="x-ios-"]:not([class*="1"]):not([class*="2"]) { background:blue; }

<div class="x-ios-1"></div>
<div class="x-ios-2"></div>
<div class="x-ios-3"></div>
<div class="x-ios-4"></div>
<div class="x-ios-5"></div>
<div class="x-ios-6"></div>
```

[image]

---

Or come up with a nth recipe for whatever your use case is..

```
:nth-child(n+5) matches children 5, 6, 7, ...
:nth-child(2n+5) matches children 5, 7, 9, ...
:nth-child(-n+7) matches children 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
:nth-child(-3n+8) matches children 2, 5, and 8
```

Comment: :nth-child() is not an option in my use case. I am going to hardcode the cases I want to exclude, that is the best I can do. Sass for loop is not an option because I don't want to generate classes for unknown future versions.

Comment: I would however change `:not([class*="1"]):not([class*="2"])` to `$=` otherwise it would match for example `x-ios-10`. But still I would have problems with `x-ios-11`. I begin to think there is no other solution than hardcoding.

Comment: For those having the same problem, this is the solution I came up with: `body[class*="x-ios-"]:not(.x-ios-6)`. Deployment target is set to 6.0, so I don't have to worry about previous versions.

Answer (score 2):

In vanilla CSS you could use the attribute selector with a wildcard to match any className that begins with "x-ios-":

```
[class*='x-ios-'] {
  /* all ios */
}
```

And then hard-code known cases that need something extra:

```
.x-ios-7 {
  /* ios 7 */
}
```

Edit: as doc's answer suggests you can target >= ios7 like this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwmb6xww/)):

```
[class*='x-ios-']:not(.x-ios-3):not(.x-ios-4):not(.x-ios-5):not(.x-ios-6) {
   /* ios >= 7 */
}
```

Comment: The point is exactly that I don't want to hardcode known cases :)