# CSS target item with class greater than n regardless of other classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

Referencing: [CSS selector to match class with number greater than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26157024/css-selector-to-match-class-with-number-greater-than)

I have an element that is created dynamically with a class attribute-flag-n where n is 0+. What I need to do is hide all items that have 3 flags or more from view.

```
[class^="attribute-flagged-"]:not([class*="0"]):not([class*="1"]):not([class*="2"]) {
  display:none;
}
```

while the above works to hide the elements. Some items have a secondary class that while it does not conflict with CSS it breaks the above from targeting it.

```
<!-- Show this -->
<li class="attribute-flagged-2">...</li>
<!-- Hide this -->
<li class="attribute-flagged-5">...</li>
<!-- Hide this -->
<li class="for-review attribute-flagged-7">...</li>
```

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this other class from interfering with the targeted reference.

[JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfr7o09m/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not matching is due to the `[class^="attribute-flagged-"]`, since sometimes the class you care about is not the first in the list of classes. It would work if you used `[class*="attribute-flagged-"]` instead. However, I suggest a more specific approach, so that it wouldn't break if any other classes contained any of those 3 digits:

```
[class*="attribute-flagged-"]:not(.attribute-flagged-0):not(.attribute-flagged-1):not(.attribute-flagged-2) {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, you are a life saver. I kept trying to do some weird exclusions of the other class but then I would have to run into problems later. Ever-Learning!