# Is it possible to have a CSS selector based on an attribute range?

Tags: html, css

Assume the following:

```
<div data-id = '1'></div>
<div data-id = '3'></div>
<div data-id = '5'></div>
<div data-id = '7'></div>
<div data-id = '11'></div>
```

Is it possible to have different background colours based on the range:

for instance:

```
<style>
  div[data-id>0:data-id<5] {background: black}
    div[data-id>4:data-id<10] {background: grey}
     div[data-id>10] {background: white}
</style>
```

Obviously I made up the syntax but I think it indicates what I'm trying to do. Is this possible in CSS alone?

Comment: Sadly, no, CSS does not evaluate things (mostly, there are caveats, but the selectors are very hardened). You could count in tens with for example `[data-id^=1]` would count 1, 10-19, 100-199, 1000-1999 etc... Not sure if thats useful.

Comment: This is similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504543/assign-css-attributes-according-to-class-range) in which you can modify to match data attributes