# Select multiple options with different values of a select element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<select>
   <option value="0"></option>
   <option value="1"></option>
   <option value="2"></option>
   <option value="3"></option>
</select>
```

Is there a way to select that options where have this values: 0, 2, 3

Something like this:

```
$('option[value=0,2,3]')
```

Comment: [This post may contain some pertinent information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504543/assign-css-attributes-according-to-class-range)

Comment: You can use `option:not([value=1])`

Comment: You cannot select more than one option if the select is not "multiple"

Comment: @mplungjan He's not trying to choose them, but match them all in code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but what if I didn't want 2 and 1? @Barmar

Comment: Then you can't do that. It was only a suggestion when you want all but one option.

Comment: @Barmar so the dupe still works `const texts = $('select [value=1],[value=2],[value=3]').map(function() { return $(this).text() }).get();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't put a list in an attribute selector.

You can use a list of selectors separated by comma, but there's no shorthand.

```js
$('option[value=0],option[value=2],option[value=3]')
```

Perhaps a better solution would be to give all those options the same class, then use a class selector.

Comment: thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

use the `:not()` css function `option:not([value=1])`

```js
const selected = $('option:not([value=1])').text('selected')

console.log(selected)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1"></option>
  <option value="2"></option>
  <option value="3"></option>
</select>
```